# Custom objects in Chatter Mobile

Tags: chatter, chatter-mobile, salesforce1-app

Using latest version of Chatter Mobile (4.2).  We have some related lists on the standard Opportunity object for custom objects.  Is there a way to prevent these from being synchronized down and displayed in Chatter Mobile?

Answer (score 1):

No, Chatter Mobile uses the same page layouts as the web version. Right now, there is no way to make a mobile version of your layouts. You can add additional pieces to Chatter Mobile such as embedded VF pages or expanded lookups, but that's about all the customization you can do right now.

Answer (score 0):

What Daniel said before is the strict truth, however there are ways to get what you're looking for.

You can build a custom visualforce page using the standard controller of your object and a custom controller extension for whatever logic you might need. Then, in your visual force page itself, iterate over a *fieldset* that you've created with the fields you want on the mobile vf page. here's the skinny on that vf page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Sales_Plan_Package__c.FieldSets.*FIELDSET_NAME_HERE*}" var="f">
    <apex:outputField value="{!f}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

so that should at least get you started.